# ID based celery queue for multiple worker using same queue

Tags: rabbitmq, celery

I'm new to celery and building a monitoring application in which the main server will get all the client node server status using celery and rabbitmq.

I have figured how to send and receive task using celery but stuck at using a single queue for multiple servers.

For eg If I have 200 servers in all

Will create 10 queues and each queue will handle 20 servers.

```
[rabbitmq_queue1....10]
```

My issue is that when a celery worker starts listening to a particular queue it fetches all the task in the queue

```
celery -A tasks worker -n celery_worker_A -Q rabbitmq_queue_1 --loglevel=DEBUG
```

So how could I give an ID to the task so that a specific worker should only pick his task and leave the rest.

Thanks for your time and help!!!

Comment: Try to run workers with `-O fair` flag.

Comment: @DejanLekic sorry for replying late was down with high fever just recovered......could you please help me with where to specify the IP  or ID searched for this -0 flag but could not find much info....

Comment: You should basically add that to your worker command line: `celery -A tasks worker -n celery_worker_A -Q rabbitmq_queue_1 --loglevel=DEBUG -O fair`

Comment: Thanks for replaying but how  do I send the message from the producer for a particular worker......like where do I mention clients Id as task gets assign to the queue and not directly to worker.....coz if a send the task to the queue then it will get picked up by any random worker which are listening to the same queue

Comment: If you want to send task to be executed by particular worker, then each worker must have a dedicated, unique queue that you send tasks to. There were multiple questions about this on StackOverflow in the past...

Comment: Actually had searched on stackoverflow and on other site but could not find one and there was didn't found that it cannot be so in search of hope had posted the question....just a last question so I'm building a monitoring system so for each server if I create a new queue is that efficient enough......and Thanks for your time!!!!

Comment: When I started learning Celery I wanted to do this, and then realised that it defeats the purpose. If you do not want tasks to be automatically distributed, then you perhaps should not use Celery at all, even though you can accomplish what you want with mentioned dedicated queues...

Comment: Thanks for time mate....appreciate your help!!!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as DejanLekic suggested we cannot assign task to a queue based on different celery worker id.

Just posted this answer so if might help someone new to celery as me.